# Android NFC always calling onCreate when app is closed

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-lifecycle, rfid

[image]I  made  app  that  detects  nfc  tag.  All  work  fine,  when  my  app  is closed  and  i  scan  the  nfc  tag  with  my  phone  it  shows  me  an  activity  have  onCreate()  method  ,  when  i  scan  again  for  the  2nd  time  it  works  ,  i  dont  know  if  im  wrong  in  the  lifecycle  of  the  app  or  that i  missed  something  in  my  code?
when i open app , scanning is working : 1st photo 
when app is closed 2nd photo : from 2nd photo but in the 2nd scan it works[image]
this  is  my  code

```
public class NfcActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "NfcActivity";

    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    private TextView mTextView;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_nfc_detail);
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cet appareil ne supporte pas nfc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Activer nfc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
//        if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) {
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())
                    || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Tag iTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                mTextView.setText(TagReader.readTag(iTag, intent));
            }
      //  }
    }
}
```

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.NfcActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: my question is how to read the nfc tag from the 1st time when my app is closed without showing activity having oncreate() method

Comment: my app is reading the nfc tag from the background but in the 2nd scan , in the 1st one its showing me (1st scan) my activity with the text view having oncreate (), so i just want to know how to show the result from the 1st scan from background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: see full solution in related:

- [How to use NFC ACTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632775/how-to-use-nfc-actions/41637825#41637825)

---

You are only processing the intent the 2nd time round.

Add a new method based on your current `onNewIntent()` method like this:

```
private void onNewNfcTag(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) 
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag iTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        mTextView.setText(TagReader.readTag(iTag, intent));
    }
}
```

Change your `onNewIntent()` to call this new method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    onNewNfcTag(intent);
}
```

Call this same method from `onCreate()` with the intent from `getIntent()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // .... your code already here
    onNewNfcTag(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: i already tried this but didnt work , thank you

Comment: i updated my question , check the photos please

Comment: @KhldRb sorry I cannot help further - have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637825/383414 and possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457406/how-to-make-android-application-listen-to-specific-nfc-chip

Comment: thank u so much i found the answer

Comment: Good - which one was it? @KhldRb

Comment: the 1st link which u suggested , thank u agin sir